# can't initialize "<" value to char variable

Tags: c, char

I was getting error message from c compiler ,when i tried to initialize "z" to char variable and tried to print using printf function,whats wrong with my code?

```
    char a="<";
    printf("%c",a);

error:
    warning: initialization of 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Comment: `char a = '<';`

Comment: Single-Quotes (`' '`) for a single character.  Double-quotes (`" "`) for a set of characters (aka. String)